# Java 8 streams, convert List of object to Map<String, Set<String>>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have already gone through few examples and those did not work for me.

Here is what I am trying to do:

I have a `List<SomeClass>` of the following class:

```
class SomeClass {
  String rid;
  String name;
  ...
}
```

The values in my `List` look like this:

```
SomeClass(1,"apple")
SomeClass(1,"banana")
SomeClass(1,"orange")
SomeClass(2,"papaya")
SomeClass(2,"peaches")
SomeClass(3,"melons")
```

I want to convert the above `List` into a `Map<String,  Set<String>>`, where key is `rid` and value is `Set` of `name` field.

To solve this using Java `Streams` I am using `groupingBy` and I could come to below solution:

```
someClassList
            .stream()
            .map(SomeClass::getName)
            .collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(
                      SomeClass::getRid, Collectors.toSet()));
```

But this gives me compilation error.
How do I solve this and what is the problem with my approach?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you call `.map(SomeClass::getName)` on your `Stream<SomeClass>`, you get a `Stream<String>`. You can't execute `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass::getRid,...))` on a `Stream<String>` (you can only execute it on a `Stream<SomeClass>`).
Therefore your `map` step is wrong.

You need to pass the `Collector` returned by `Collectors.mapping()` to `Collectors.groupingBy()` in order to map the `SomeClass` instances to `String`s **after** they are grouped by `getRid`.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map =
    someClassList.stream()
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SomeClass::getRid, 
                                                Collectors.mapping(SomeClass::getName,
                                                                   Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: Thanks, that was quick :)

Answer (score 3):

Although not as readable as the `groupingBy` collector; you can use the `toMap` collector just as well:

```
myList.stream()
      .collect(toMap(SomeClass::getRid, e -> new HashSet<>(singleton(e.getName())), 
                 (l, r) -> {l.addAll(r); return l;}));
```

Ensure that you have the necessary imports for `singleton` and `toMap` or you can just use `Collectors.toMap(...)` and `Collections.singleton(...)` respectively.

Comment: That’s what I use when I expect most of the groups to be rather small. `.collect(toMap(SomeClass::getRid, e -> singleton(e.getName()), (l, r) -> { if(l.size() == 1) { l = new HashSet<>(l); } l.addAll(r); return l;}));` if you want to use it in parallel, it might be worth to extend the merge function to check the sizes and add the smaller set to the bigger set.